# Clean approach to devise notice/alerts in materialize toast

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, devise, erb, materialize

I'm using devise in my rails app and as standard it comes with `notice` and `alert` methods which render on specific actions (e.g. a user signing in).

I am also using the [Materialize CSS](http://materializecss.com/) framework and they provide a nice clean ['Toast' style notification](http://materializecss.com/dialogs.html). This is the first approach at making `notice` and `alert` work with Toast.

```
<% if notice %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    Materialize.toast('<%= notice %>', 4000)
  </script>
<% end %>
<% if alert %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    Materialize.toast('<%= alert %>', 4000)
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Can anyone provide a cleaner/more DRY solution? Feels a little hacky.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It mast be not the "hackyest" way, but still a bit DRYer:

> ```
> <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
>     <%= javascript_tag "Materialize.toast('#{message}', 4000)" %>
> <% end %>
> ```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think I'd necessarily consider that technique 'hacky'. This works well for me in my production app:

```
<% flash.each do |type, message| %>
  <% if type == "success" %>
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      <i class="icon-check"></i>
      <p><%= message.html_safe %></p>
    </div>
  <% elsif type == "toast" %>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        Materialize.toast("<%= message %>", 3000);
      });
    </script>
  <% else %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      <i class="icon-notice"></i>
      <%= message.html_safe %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Just my opinion here, but I don't see anything wrong with that.

Bottom line is I don't think there is a way out of the box to have your flash trigger js other than doing it this way (but I'm all ears if someone thinks they have a better solution).

Comment: This could be better. The alert html is really similar. Should really be abstracted to one div there.

Comment: use double-quotes in the: Materialize.toast('<%= message %>' ... otherwise if there is an apostrophe in the message the message won't be displayed

Comment: Good all @jpwynn. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

here is my solution.. The main code is only two lines.

```
<% unless flash.empty? %>
    <script>
      <% flash.each do |f| %>
      <% type=f[0].to_s.gsub('alert', 'red').gsub('warning', 'orange').gsub('success', 'green') %>
      Materialize.toast('<%= f[1] %>', 4000, '<%= type %>')
      <% end %>
    </script>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split your code in two part.  First, pass flash messages to js in erb. Second, trigger toast in your script.
Take a look at https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/unobtrusive_flash